# CSS to display html content like Windows 8 Apps Grids

Tags: css, html, windows-8

I like the look of the grids for Windows Store Apps and trying to recreate this with standard web technique (IE10 and up, FF, Chrome, Safari). Grids in Windows Store Apps scroll vertical and the content is split into Columns that you have to read top down.

So far I have a div that scrolls horizontal with a fixed height:

```
.scroll-horizontal {    
   overflow-x:scroll;
   overflow-y:hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This works fine but there is a problem with the child elements warping. They are normally lined up under each other. But I need them to wrap to the next column if the height of the element is reached. Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bwwP2/3/) and a image of what I want to archive:
[image]

How can i get the child elements wrap like a Windows 8 App grid with CSS?

Comment: With pure CSS I don't believe you can. You'll need JS (/JQuery) to calculate the amount of divs that fit in the height of the parent. When it overflows, create a new column.

Comment: i read about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). But I didn't know how to use it. Maybe itÄs possible with flexboxes. I really like to have  a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution: CSS3 [columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) let the content wrap if it reached the height of an element:

```
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-width: 320px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 32px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-width: 320px;
    -moz-column-gap: 32px;
    column-fill: auto;
    column-width: 320px;
    column-gap: 32px;
```

Answer (score 1):

please refer to [Metro UI css](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS)  .It will satisfy all of your needs as writing the whole css  here is timetaking.

Comment: nice, thanks for the link. But they also don't seem to have a solution for my problem.